# date picker take same values of date

Tags: jquery, html, datetimepicker

I have two date picker to select start date and end date.when I select date from 1st its work fine but when I select date from 2nd date picker it overwrites the date of first selected.
My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="datetimepicker_css.js" /></script>
<table align="left" class="tbl_altcolor shadow" style="width:35%; margin-left:20px">
<tbody>
<tr>
     <td>Date-From:</td>
      <td>
         <input type="Text" id="demo3" class="input required" maxlength="20" size="15" name="time3">
         <img src="images2/date.png" align="center" width="20" height="20" border="0" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('demo3','yyyyMMdd')" style="cursor:pointer"/>
        <span class="descriptions"></span>
        </td>

         <td>Date-To:</td>
      <td>
         <input type="Text" id="demo2" class="input required" maxlength="20" size="15" name="time5">
         <img src="images2/date.png" align="center" width="20" height="20" border="0" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('demo3','yyyyMMdd')" style="cursor:pointer"/>
        <span class="descriptions"></span>
        </td>
</tr>
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle that shows your issue? This doesnt give enough information at this moment

Comment: there are two rows date from and date to.

Comment: <td>Date-To:</td>
<td>
<input type="Text" id="demo2" class="input required" maxlength="20" size="15" name="time5">
<img src="images2/date.png" align="center" width="20" height="20" border="0" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('demo3','yyyyMMdd')" style="cursor:pointer"/>
<span class="descriptions"></span>
      </td>

Comment: If i can see the date-from i can possible help

Comment: <tr>
<td>Date-From:</td>
<td>
<input type="Text" id="demo3" class="input required" maxlength="20" size="15" name="time3"> <img src="images2/date.png" align="center" width="20" height="20" border="0" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('demo3','yyyyMMdd')" style="cursor:pointer"/>
<span class="descriptions"></span>
</td></tr>
<tr>
 <td>Date-To:</td>
     <span class="descriptions"></span>
      </td>
 </tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On clicking the image, your code triggers this:

```
javascript:NewCssCal('demo3','yyyyMMdd')
```

it is triggering the calendar on input with id `demo3` while the element you provided in you example has an id `demo2`:

```
<input type="Text" id="demo2" class="input required" maxlength="20" size="15" name="time5">
```

Therefore ensure that you elements have the proper id and and correctly being referred to when the click is triggered.

The **HTML** code should be:

```
<table align="left" class="tbl_altcolor shadow" style="width:35%; margin-left:20px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Date-From:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="Text" id="demo2" class="input required" maxlength="20" size="15" name="time3">
                <img src="http://www.rainforestnet.com/datetimepicker/images2/cal.gif" align="center" width="20" height="20" border="0" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('demo2','yyyyMMdd')" style="cursor:pointer" />    <span class="descriptions"></span>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date-To:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="Text" id="demo3" class="input required" maxlength="20" size="15" name="time5">
                <img src="http://www.rainforestnet.com/datetimepicker/images2/cal.gif" align="center" width="20" height="20" border="0" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('demo3','yyyyMMdd')" style="cursor:pointer" />    <span class="descriptions"></span>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/0e1xbdcc/1/)

Comment: Have changed it.But  no success

Comment: Please do provide you code in a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/). It will be easier to help :)

Comment: @soni8010 I updated my answer and JSFiddle link to the demo. It works. The error was still that you did not give individual IDs to each element. An element should *always* have a unique ID on a page.